# Java Web Start download the latest JRE?

Tags: java, security, versioning, java-web-start

In my JNLP file, I'm using the following to make sure Java 7 users will run my application under Java 6:

`<j2se version="1.6" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>`

It works, and will even prompt to install Java 6 if necessary. However, when Java 6 is installed, it is version 1.6.0.0 (!) which obviously is a security risk.

How to get JWS to download the latest version of Java 6 (or any version that's specified in the j2se tag)?

Comment: See also [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) (emphasis mine):

> The version attribute refers, by default, to a platform version (specification version) of the Java Platform Standard Edition. [...]
>   **Exact product versions (implementation versions) may also be specified by including the href attribute.**

So I guess that removing the `href` part should do what you expect:

```
<j2se version="1.6">
```

Comment: +1 and accepted answer. Today it tried to download J2RE 1.6.0_35 Installer when I left off the `HREF` part. It's not quite 1.6.0_37, but I'll take it.